# "channel allocation failed: refusing due to active shutdown" warning

Tags: asterisk

Our phones are down with the warning above when I try to run command show channels.  Is a core restart was done, how long before phones back up?  Or is there something else that needs to be done to get phones back up?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking this, you should not be responsible for a production Asterisk system!

The warning means that Asterisk is in the process of shutting down.  Look at your Asterisk full message log to find out WHY a shutdown is in progress.  Did Asterisk crash?  Did it get a term signal?  Was the service stopped?  Etc.